# Authenticating lots of clients for a REST API

Tags: rest, authentication

We have a large number of small devices deployed in the wild that communicate with a central server via a REST API. It will send a status update on a regular basis with some sensor data and will also ask the server if there are any software updates that need to be applied. If there are, it will download it etc.

I'd like some way to prevent my server API from being used by unauthorised clients. Here are the solutions that I have and the issues which I anticipate. This question is somewhat open ended but it is mostly a question of best practices for, what I think is, a common situation.

1. Keep a single username/password on the server and then use basic auth over https. This is simple but if I change it, I'd have to somehow change the credentials on *all* of my devices (which number in the low thousands). This is hard to do reliably. There's also a problem with how the devices are going to get the update without first changing their creds.
2. The second is to create a username/password for every device. Then I can update individual ones and manage them but there's a lot of state on the server and I'm worried about having this much data on the server.
3. Some kind of automatic key based system whereby the devices can ask for an expirable key and then use that for all transactions. If the key expires or is invalidated, that device can't connect anymore. This would necessitate some kind of id for the device which I'm not sure how to handle.

So, how would I do this?

### Update

In our setup, we have assigned hostnames for each of the devices we're going to deploy created beforehand. Once the devices switch on, they will contact the server with their hostnames and thereby register themselves. The MAC address and other information is passed as part of the initial registration handshake.

So, the "unique identifer" which was mentioned in the answer (and comment) by Noksi is the hostname. This can be easily spoofed (since the hostnames have a pattern). However, when the devices first come online, we can get the mac and, after that, only refresh the token if the request comes from the same mac. This opens up the possibility of a fake registration happening the first time though.

Comment: If there is some way to uniquely identify each device (similar to a MAC address) then that would be the key. Keep a registry of the devices and each device would register with the server. the server would provide the device with a token and associate it (the token) with the registered device. the device uses that token to make requests. tokens can be made to expire and renewed as needed or can be black listed if needed. This seems to be similar to option 3 in the proposed options.

Comment: This was exactly they way my thoughts wandered too. We do have a registry of MAC addresses which can uniquely identify each device.

Comment: Then there is your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is some way to uniquely identify each device (similar to a MAC address) then that would be the key. Keep a registry of the devices and each device would register with the server. the server would provide the device with a token and associate it (the token) with the registered device. the device uses that token to make requests. tokens can be made to expire and renewed as needed or can be black listed if needed. This seems to be similar to option 3 in the proposed options.

Comment: I've updated my answer with something that might alter the scheme a little.